# .NET Core 3.1 - redirect from middleware not working

Tags: asp.net-core, redirect, middleware

I try to redirect to a custom error page when I get a particular status

but any request to my api is processed without problem, instead of receiving a code 301/302

even if I do the redirect on any request

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Leads2WinDBContext context)
{
    ... // some sensitive identification code here

    await next(httpContext);

    //if (httpContext.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)
    {
        httpContext.Response.Redirect("/error");
    }
}
```

anything I am doing wrong ?

thanks for your help

Comment: If you need to redirect, remove `await next(context)` (or put it inside an `if()` block) to prevent other middleware from running.

Comment: Additionally, ASP.NET Core already includes an error middleware (`app.UseExceptionHandler()`) which does this redirection for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I know but I have been asked to redirect to a page that gives less informations for security reasons

Comment: Exception handler doesn't expose sensitive information unless you expose it yourself. It allows customization too. Check out the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-handler-page

Comment: Hi @phil123456, I have tested your code, it could get 302 redirect. Could you please how do you register the middleware and more details about your middleware?

Answer (score 0):

app.UseExceptionHandler() was already in my code, I just changed it to point to a custom error page